# Do I still use local host once I deploy my react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, backend, port

I am currently building the backend for my react-native app, and I was wondering:

I have the app.listen("insert port"). This works fine, but when I want to deploy to lets say, the app store, do I need to change it? I mean, does my app have to keep loading on my local host? Or do I use some other port.

Thank you.

Comment: It's rather uncommon to add a backend server to the store. You should host the server somewhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

so when you do local development the app is actually listening to a js bundler on that port, which hot reloads(recompiles the changes instantly and shows you the change), this behaviour is slow and not needed in production apps which are deployed on stores.

Hence you precompile the js into a bundle and add it into the APK/IPA as a asset, so your base app reads the bundled code from the js bundle asset path and not the listener. Hence your app will not keep loading on local host and will have its own copy of js code bundled with it

Intructions to create a build - https://reactnative.dev/docs/publishing-to-app-store#3-build-app-for-release

Comment: do hit like if it answers your question

Comment: Hi, I'd like to ask, I need to access data from API. For that do I need to deploy my code somewhere? I mean how do I configure it to work in production, because it is only working in development mode.